# How to create a PDF with several pages of images, and titles keeping their quality?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I want to create a short portfolio in PDF format, by including one image from a jpeg file, and a text title.

I've tried doing this with Word and then print those "pages" as one PDF, but the image quality is getting worse. It needs to remain pixel perfect quality as the original image. (turning off the compress images in Word settings did not help).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In the Word export dialogue, use the options to tailor the export quality. Particularly, `Optimize for image quality`.

To get there, choose `File` > `Export`

[image]

And then on the Publish as PDF dialog click `Options`

[image]

[image]

You might also like to try toggling `Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded`, as this can sometimes rasterize the text making it look poor in quality.

Comment: I'm using Word 2013, not sure where is this dialog?

Comment: In 2013 I seem to have less options under export, and the result is the same as printing the file using a PDF printer, still bad quality.

Comment: What about using the online convertor? https://www.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/online/word-to-pdf.html

Comment: using the non-compressed option plus the online convertor certainly does seem to look better now, still not crystal sharp as the image (I can already see within the word file that it's getting somewhat pixelated), but already a major advancement - thanks!

Comment: You could try using Word Online. I am unsure of its options but it is worth looking at. https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar problem with Word 2016:
I had a word document with 600dpi PNG-Files, which I wanted to convert to PDF.

Despite all best settings in word (no compression) all "save as", "export" or 3rd-party tools as PDFcreator resulted in PDFs with a maximum of 300dpi image resolution.

Then I found instructions on [Microsoft troubleshooting page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/image-dpi-change-after-print-to-pdf):

- Add new registry key under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options` (original site says 15.0 for Word 2013 and 14.0 for Word 2010)
- Registry Value Name: `PrintHighQualityDefault`
- Registry Value Type: `REG_DWORD`
- Registry Value Data: `1`

This fixed it for me and my PDF, at least the ones created with PDFCreator, showed the desired quality.

Comment: similarly, there is also an undocumented PrintShapesAsVector options for PowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get a PDF from Word without losing quality and without any compression, is using the "Save as Adobe PDF" feature from Adobe Acrobat, and saving **all** the pages, otherwise pictures are compressed again for some obscure reason...